# SQL syntax error on ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, web-deployment

I have this table that I want to update / insert with one statement currently using ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE:

```
index (INT) user(INT) entryId(INT) tags(text)
1              1          111      ||bla||
2              1          111      ||bla||
3              1          111      ||bla||
```

> INSERT INTO filters (index,user,entryId,tags) VALUES
>   (1,1,'100003817186741',"||test1||||test2||"),
>   (3,1,'100003021196089',"||test1||||test2||") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
>   user=VALUES(user),entryId=VALUES(entryId),tags=VALUES(tags)

Why does this fail with an SQL syntax error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It fails because `index` is a MySQL reserved word.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

either wrap it in backticks or choose another word for it

```
INSERT INTO filters (index,user,entryId,tags)
                     ^    ^
```

do

```
INSERT INTO filters (`index`,user,entryId,tags)
```

Comment: user also reserved word

Comment: @DmitryBezik `user` is not a reserved word, but `use` is.

Comment: Yep sry, user not reserved word

Comment: @Tzvi Hi, just a quick note to see if you can tick the checkmark to close the question, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

index is a SQL reserved words, you must rewrite your query

```
INSERT INTO filters (`index`,`user`,entryId,tags) VALUES (1,1,'100003817186741',"||test1||||test2||"), (3,1,'100003021196089',"||test1||||test2||") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `user`=VALUES(`user`),entryId=VALUES(entryId),tags=VALUES(tags)
```

Comment: Could you tell me where [in the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) where you saw `user` being a reserved word?

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax looks strange with four vertical bars together and mixing single quotes and double quotes.

```
INSERT INTO filters(index, user, entryId, tags)
    VALUES (1, 1, '100003817186741', "||test1||||test2|| "),  
           (3, 1, '100003021196089', "||test1||||test2|| ")
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE user=VALUES(user),entryId=VALUES(entryId),tags=VALUES(tags);
```

I would write this more like:

```
INSERT INTO filters(`index`, `user`, entryId, tags)
    SELECT 1, 1, '100003817186741', CONCAT('||', test1, '||', test2) UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 1, '100003021196089', CONCAT('||', test1, '||', test2)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `user` = VALUES(`user`),
                            entryId = VALUES(entryId),
                            tags = VALUES(tags);
```

That is, using the explicit `concat()` function.  The use of `select` instead of `values` is just a personal preference -- `select . . . union all` does everything `values` does and more.

Also, avoid using reserved words such as `index` as column or table names.  These are reserved words and SQL is much more readable without escape characters.